# Doctrine: No identifier/primary key specified for

Tags: symfony, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

So I have everything set but I still get:

> No identifier/primary key specified for Entity
>   "Bisna\Application\Entity\Company". Every Entity must have an
>   identifier/primary key.

**Entity:**

```
<?php
namespace Bisna\Application\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="companies")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Company{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $industry
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CompanyIndustry", inversedBy="company_industry")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="industry_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $industry;

    /**
     * @var string $billingAddress
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BillingAddress", inversedBy="billing_addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="billing_address_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $billingAddress;

    /**
     * @var string $companyName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="companyName", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $companyName;

    /**
     * @var string $website
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="website", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $website;

    /**
     * @var string $address
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @var string $employeesNumber
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="employees_number", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $employeesNumber;

    /**
     * @var string $streetNumber
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="street_number", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $streetNumber;

    /**
     * @var string $street
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * @var string $city
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @var string $cityVarname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city_varname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $cityVarname;

    /**
     * @var string $state
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $state;

    /**
     * @var string $stateVarname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state_varname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $stateVarname;

    /**
     * @var string $stateCode
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $stateCode;

    /**
     * @var string $postalCode
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="postal_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $postalCode;

    /**
     * @var string $country
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $country;

    /**
     * @var string $countryVarname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_varname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $countryVarname;

    /**
     * @var string $countryCode
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $countryCode;

    /**
     * @var string $latitude
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $latitude;

    /**
     * @var string $longitude
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $longitude;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string $password
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @var string $firstname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string $lastname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastName", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @var Collection $jobs
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompanyJob", mappedBy="company", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"created" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $jobs;

    /**
     * @var string $activationCode
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="activationCode", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $activationCode;

    /**
     * @var string $resetPasswordCode
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="resetPasswordCode", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $resetPasswordCode;

    /**
     * @var string $status ['activation', 'active', 'inactive']
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $created;

    /* .... */
}
```

I haven't made the tables yet, but still, I don't understand why I'm getting this error since I have everything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because you missed a `@` before `@ORM\Column` annotation for `$id` property?

You should consider using Yaml doctrine mappings. It's a good way to separate entity from database columns definitions. And besides, your IDE should validate Yaml contents whereas it probably doesn't validate PHP comments as PHP code.

Comment: Make sure you cleared the cache after adding the @ back in.

Comment: $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
        $cacheDriver->deleteAll(); I have tried like this but no luck, I will try to create the table maybe...

Comment: It Was the cache